# Change xml configuration file based on jenkins build variables

Tags: jenkins

```
if i have the following manifest 
    <sitemanifest>
      <IisApp path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Single Sign On\Output\2.0.233.1258\QuickRelease" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"/>
      <setAcl path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Single Sign On\Output\2.0.233.1258\QuickRelease" setAclResourceType="Directory"  setAclUser="anonymousAuthenticationUser" /> 
    </sitemanifest>
```

Is it possible to inject build parameters from a jenkins job?
This is useful for me since I can then have a dedicated jenkins job that executes a backup of the site before deploying to it.

It's then used by all my deployments so it's modular and repeatable.

Comment: It is possible. What are the parameters you want to pass?

Comment: its a string TO SWAP OUT  the path attribute with whatever i pass in. i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Single Sign On\Output\2.0.233.1258\QuickRelease to say c:\C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\SomeOthersite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parameterize the paths in your manifest file like the following:

```
<sitemanifest>
      <IisApp path="$path" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"/>
      <setAcl path="$path1" setAclResourceType="Directory"  setAclUser="anonymousAuthenticationUser" /> 
</sitemanifest>
```

Then create a freestyle job in Jenkins and in job configuration in general section choose `This project is parameterized` and create two `string` parameters `path` and `path1`.

Then choose `Execute Shell` and add the following script into it and save the job:

```
envsubst '$path' < /path/to/manifest
envsubst '$path1' < /path/to/manifest
```

The `envsubst` program substitutes the values of variables.

then when you build the job it will ask for two parameters `path` and `path1`, provide the required path and build the job.

This should do the trick.